# Telnet/TcpClient C# Skipping Code and not iterating through loop

Tags: c#, loops, telnet, tcpclient

this is going to sound silly but for some reason this code seems to skip over the read. Or maybe it is going too fast? I'm trying to get a telnet response from the server and I get the first line response but nothing more. It doesn't matter how many readline() I put or if I try to sleep the thread. What can I do to get the whole response from the server to be printed? I think I narrowed the problem down to exiting. In the sample program if you hard code the exit, it immediately ends the loop and displays nothing. I tried sleeping the thread but that just seemed to stop everything.

Output:

```
220 server-12.tower-558.messagelabs.com ESMTP
```

Expected Output:

```
250-server-11.tower-555.messagelabs.com says EHLO to iphere
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
```

My Code:

```
 //Telnet Start
 IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.Resolve(list[j]);
 TelnetConnection tc = new TelnetConnection(hostInfo.AddressList[0].ToString(), 25);
 string prompt = "a";
 string consoleout = "";
 // while connected
 while (tc.IsConnected && prompt != "exit")
 {
 // display server output
 prompt = "ehlo a.com";
 tc.WriteLine(prompt);
 //I've tried adding a 2 or 5 second thread sleep here and I still get the same result.
 Console.Write(tc.Read());
 prompt = "exit";
 }
 //Telnet End
```

TelnetConnection Class:

```
// minimalistic telnet implementation
// conceived by Tom Janssens on 2007/06/06  for codeproject
//
// http://www.corebvba.be



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace MinimalisticTelnet
{
    enum Verbs {
        WILL = 251,
        WONT = 252,
        DO = 253,
        DONT = 254,
        IAC = 255
    }

    enum Options
    {
        SGA = 3
    }

    class TelnetConnection
    {
        TcpClient tcpSocket;

        int TimeOutMs = 100;

        public TelnetConnection(string Hostname, int Port)
        {
            try
            {
                tcpSocket = new TcpClient(Hostname, Port);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.Write(e);
            }

        }

        public string Login(string Username,string Password,int LoginTimeOutMs)
        {
            int oldTimeOutMs = TimeOutMs;
            TimeOutMs = LoginTimeOutMs;
            string s = Read();
            if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
               throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no login prompt");
            WriteLine(Username);

            s += Read();
            if (!s.TrimEnd().EndsWith(":"))
                throw new Exception("Failed to connect : no password prompt");
            WriteLine(Password);

            s += Read();
            TimeOutMs = oldTimeOutMs;
            return s;
        }

        public void WriteLine(string cmd)
        {
            Write(cmd + "\n");
        }

        public void Write(string cmd)
        {
            if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return;
            byte[] buf = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd.Replace("\0xFF","\0xFF\0xFF"));
            tcpSocket.GetStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        }

        public string Read()
        {
            if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return null;
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            do
            {
                ParseTelnet(sb);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
            } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public bool IsConnected
        {
            get { return tcpSocket.Connected; }
        }

        void ParseTelnet(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            while (tcpSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                int input = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                switch (input)
                {
                    case -1 :
                        break;
                    case (int)Verbs.IAC:
                        // interpret as command
                        int inputverb = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                        if (inputverb == -1) break;
                        switch (inputverb)
                        {
                            case (int)Verbs.IAC: 
                                //literal IAC = 255 escaped, so append char 255 to string
                                sb.Append(inputverb);
                                break;
                            case (int)Verbs.DO: 
                            case (int)Verbs.DONT:
                            case (int)Verbs.WILL:
                            case (int)Verbs.WONT:
                                // reply to all commands with "WONT", unless it is SGA (suppres go ahead)
                                int inputoption = tcpSocket.GetStream().ReadByte();
                                if (inputoption == -1) break;
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)Verbs.IAC);
                                if (inputoption == (int)Options.SGA )
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WILL:(byte)Verbs.DO); 
                                else
                                    tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte(inputverb == (int)Verbs.DO ? (byte)Verbs.WONT : (byte)Verbs.DONT); 
                                tcpSocket.GetStream().WriteByte((byte)inputoption);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        sb.Append( (char)input );
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Using the following loop I was able to get it to work once, but only once it would not iterate through the count of j when I verified that j was 2. My output, expected output and function are below.

Function:

```
for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
{
//Telnet Start
Console.WriteLine("On round #" + j);
IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.Resolve(list[j]);
TelnetConnection tc = new TelnetConnection(hostInfo.AddressList[0].ToString(), 25);
string prompt = "a";
string consoleout = "";
// while connected
while (tc.IsConnected && prompt != "exit")
{
// display server output
Console.Write(tc.Read());

// send client input to server
prompt = "ehlo a.com";
tc.WriteLine(prompt);

// display server output
consoleout = tc.Read();
Console.Write(consoleout);

//send exit input to server
prompt = "exit";
tc.WriteLine(prompt);
Console.Write(tc.Read());
}
Console.WriteLine("**DISCONNECTED**");
//Telnet End
if (consoleout.IndexOf("STARTTLS")>-1)
{
if (j == 0)
{
if (list[j].Contains(domains[i]))
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(domains[i], list[j], "Y", numberemployees, "Y");
else
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(domains[i], list[j], "Y", numberemployees, "N");
}
else
{
if (list[j].Contains(domains[i]))
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, list[j], "Y", null, "Y");
else
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, list[j], "Y", null, "N");
}
}
else
{
if (j == 0)
{
if (list[j].Contains(domains[i]))
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(domains[i], list[j], "N", numberemployees, "Y");
else
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(domains[i], list[j], "N", numberemployees, "N");
}
else
{
if (list[j].Contains(domains[i]))
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, list[j], "N", null, "Y");
else
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, list[j], "N", null, "N");
}
}

}
```

Output:

```
On round #0
True220 server-6.tower-95.messagelabs.com ESMTP
250-server-6.tower-95.messagelabs.com
250-STARTTLS
250-PIPELINING
250 8BITMIME
502 unimplemented (#5.5.1)
**DISCONNECTED**
On round #1
True220 server-14.tower-558.messagelabs.com ESMTP
**DISCONNECTED**
```

Expected Output:

```
On round #0
True220 server-6.tower-95.messagelabs.com ESMTP
250-server-6.tower-95.messagelabs.com
250-STARTTLS
250-PIPELINING
250 8BITMIME
502 unimplemented (#5.5.1)
**DISCONNECTED**
On round #1
True220 server-14.tower-558.messagelabs.com ESMTP
250-STARTTLS
250-PIPELINING
250 8BITMIME
**DISCONNECTED**
```

So for whatever reason, it simply won't do the second loop. But it also is starting to depend on the server. Some servers respond with a little information and some I get something like this, which makes it look like nothing happened at all.

```
On round #0
True220 SMTP Proxy Server Ready
**DISCONNECTED**
On round #1
True220 SMTP Proxy Server Ready
**DISCONNECTED**
On round #2
True220 SMTP Server Ready
**DISCONNECTED**
On round #3
True220 SMTP Server Ready
**DISCONNECTED**
On round #4
True220 SMTP Proxy Server Ready
**DISCONNECTED**
On round #5
True220 SMTP Proxy Server Ready
**DISCONNECTED**
```

Comment: Try doing something like `var response = tc.Read();`, then put a breakpoint at it to help figure out where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Ok on first pass through it does contain this: "220 server-10.tower-555.messagelabs.com ESMTP\r\n". When it goes through a second time it contains an empty string. It still just seems to get stuck at the first line of response from the server.

Comment: Your error handling is strange. In case of error you just do nothing. That's almost never appropriate.

Comment: You can't use Available that way. Research, what it does and why it is almost always a mistake.

Comment: available? Are you talking about my try catch exception block? I was trying to catch and view it so I could see what went wrong.

Comment: Sry, I meant the `Available` property. Probably part of your problem.

Comment: Ok I see, well I did not write that class, so what would be the best way to modify that code then?

Comment: Ok my socket.available is 0 which is why most of that code isn't executing, how can I fix that?

Comment: Remove usages of the Available property! Understand what it does. You haven't looked at the docs as it seems. Also, this code assumes that Read/Receive returns more than one byte. This is a mistaken assumption.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know enough to fix it at this point. I know what available does but I do not know what I would replace it with. Google is not helping with alternatives to available since many people are saying that it has a bug of showing 0 when the connection closes and not necessarily that there is no data left in the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kyle,

It looks like you need to open the socket:

```
   public string Read()
    {
        if (!tcpSocket.Connected)
        {
          throw new Exception("Socket is Closed.");
        }
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            ParseTelnet(sb);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
        } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

It isn't open, so it is returning.

**[UPDATE]**

Try looping through `IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.Resolve(list[j]);` before your `//Telnet Start` comment:

```
private const int PORT25 = 25; // I hate magic numbers

foreach (var item in list) {
  var hostInfo = Dns.Resolve(item);
  Console.WriteLine(hostInfo);
  foreach (var address in hostInfo.AddressList) {
    var tc = new TelnetConnection(address, PORT25);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} TelnetConnection Connected: {1}", address, tc.IsConnected);
  }
}
```

**[Update 2]**

This is really hard to debug, not knowing what all you are trying to connect to and what else is going on.

That said, let's try the following:

In your class `MinimalisticTelnet`, add this method:

```
public void Close() {
    if (tcpSocket != null) {
        tcpSocket.Close();
    }
}
```

I don't see it anywhere else, and that could be causing some issues the next time you attempt your second connection.

Now, in your test code, add the new one line of code after the *while loop*:

```
while (tc.IsConnected && prompt != "exit") {
    // display server output
    Console.Write(tc.Read());

    // send client input to server
    prompt = "ehlo a.com";
    tc.WriteLine(prompt);

    // display server output
    consoleout = tc.Read();
    Console.Write(consoleout);

    //send exit input to server
    prompt = "exit";
    tc.WriteLine(prompt);
    Console.Write(tc.Read());
}
tc.Close();
Console.WriteLine("**DISCONNECTED**");
```

With any luck, the reason your 2nd connection was failing was because you still had an open connection.

Comment: Thanks for the response but just to clarify, isn't that what's happening in the TelnetConnection function? I'm also completely new to sockets so how would I go about opening it?

Comment: Yes, but in the code you have posted for the TelnetConnection class, nothing ever opens the socket. Instead of having `return null;` - tell it to connect.

Comment: Ok but if I add that, I get: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connect request was made on an already connected socket

Comment: Also to verify I left the try catch block the way it is and added Console.Write(tcpSocket.Connected); which returned true.

Comment: Try adding the error checking (like the thrown exception I added). If you get past it, you know you are connected.

Comment: I did add your code and not exception was thrown. So it would appear as though my socket is connected, but, not printing correctly.

Comment: Ok my socket.available is 0 which is why most of that code isn't executing, how can I fix that?

Comment: The address is probably bad. It may be a loopback address or other non-telnet port. Try the updated code I posted, put breakpoints on the `Console.WriteLine` portions, and inspect what addresses the code is trying to open.

Comment: Ok I tried to implement your code but, it doesn't seem to recognize the address variable and is giving me an overload warning.

Comment: What's most interesting is the sample project which can be gotten from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library works flawlessly.

Comment: He is only connecting to one host, `gobelijn`, and he is relying on the Garbage Collector to disconnect the connection when he is finished with it. Since you are opening several connections, see how it works if you add the 2nd updated code snippet above that closes the connection.

Comment: Wow that fixed it!! You deserve a medal.

Comment: Thanks for your help. [I have a quick side question to ask](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55010/discussion-between-kyle-and-jp2code).

Comment: Answered with file link.

Answer (score 0):

I solve a so similar problem adding 3 reads, then 8 seconds timeout and finally reading again AND SHOWING IN MY RICHTEXBOX:

---

string r1 = conexion.Read();

string r2 = conexion.Read();

string r3 = conexion.Read();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);

richtextbox.AppendText(r1 + r2 + r3);

---

I hope it can help you!

Tell me if it works to you.